# JTextField keyevent handling issue

Tags: jtextfield

Doesn't .getKeyCode( ) return the key's int value?  Because I have set my JTextField to listen to a keylistener, and in the keytyped method, I check what key has been pressed.  Here's a snippet of my code:

```
JTextField jtf = new JTextField( );
jtf.addKeyListener( this );
.
.
.
public void keyTyped( KeyEvent e )
{
  if( e.getKeyCode( ) == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER ) System.out.println( "pressed enter" );
}
```

but everytime I type enter in the JTextField, nothing happens, ie nothing prints.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should check first if you event handler is actually get called when you pressed anything... or if your event handler is able to receive KeyEvents objects, i believe the problem lies there... for it to work, the component must have focus... [Java Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Comment: yes the keyevent handler is responding, but how do i make my jtextfield respond to "enter" key events?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are comparing the wrong values. `e.getKeyCode()` returns the key, then i guess `KeyEvent.VK_ENTER` is something really different.

Answer (score 0):

`VK_ENTER` corresponds to the int value of the enter key, seeing as how it is a constant. You should be using input and action maps from the swing class to listen for the key values when the `JTextField` is in focus as opposed to applying a key listener to the text field and listening for one key. Because an event is created (although may or may not be handled) every time a key is pressed, you should prevent the method from running when keys that aren't the enter key are pressed. Therefore preventing runtime errors and unnecessary method calls.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out a better way. you should put all your key methods inside an inner class just under your main class, Put your GUI construction code in a constructor method again out side of your main method. now. have you're inner method implement the KeyListener interface, and instantiate the three abstract methods associated with said interface, you're only using the keyTyped(KeyEvent e) method. inside that method, instantiate an int variable called keyHit and assign it to e.getKeyChar(); then put an if statement that states if(keyHit == '\n') the \n will corresopnd to the ENTER key,

I tried to post a template of the code Iused to get it to work, but It was a little long to go through and indent so if you're really need it i'll send it to you via some e-mail address or something

Comment: If you post your snippet, select it, and click on the braces symbol, it indents and highlights

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement **KeyListener** Inteface and override the **keyTyped** method in your class definition to use

```
jtf.addKeyListener(this).
```

Replace the above line  with

```
jtf.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if( e.getKeyCode( ) == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER )   
            System.out.println( "pressed enter" );
    }
});
```